# How to getText concatenating 2 strings in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, string

I have 2 variables that get the texts: `locationDisplayed` and `bindisplayed`.

I want the 3rd variable: `expectedDescription` concats the text of the first 2 vars.

Here is the code:

```js
let locationDisplayed = element(by.css('.badge-primary')).getText().then(function (text) {

        }); //location to be compared with Destination field
           
        let bindisplayed = element(by.css('.badge-info')).getText().then(function (text) {

        }); //bin to be compared with Destination field
        
        let expectedDescription = locationDisplayed + " "+bindisplayed;
        expectedDescription.getText().then(function(text){
            console.log(text);

        });
```

But then I got: `expectedDescription.getText is not a function`.

Anyone knows how can I concat 2 strings, and get the string of this concatenation?

Comment: Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `getText()` could be called on a DOM element (https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText), but you're using this function on a string. That won't work.

If you just want to concatenate `expectedDescription` and  `locationDisplayed`, you've actually done that already on this line: `let expectedDescription = locationDisplayed + " "+bindisplayed;`

Another way might be to use `str.concat()` function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat).

Comment: hi @pavelsaman, I want to print in the console the result of this concatenation, so I can assure the result is what I want. So I am trying to do:```let expectedDescription = locationDisplayed + " "+bindisplayed;
         expectedDescription.getText().then(function(text){
             console.log(text);```

Comment: @IngriddBrito: you can print the concatenated string into the console like this `console.log(expectedDescription)`

Comment: I  just added onsole.log(expectedDescription) as you suggested and it worked. Tks!

Comment: @IngriddBrito your code is too brittle, it breaks when the element takes more time to render. Use the proper chaining or await. In your case even if you remove then , it behaves the same way

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the fact that everything is a promise in protractor.

In your code, you are not waiting for the promise to be resolved.

There are two ways :

**First: Using await**

Add the below line in your config file:

```
 SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false
```

Then rewrite the code as below:

```
    let locationDisplayed = await element(by.css('.badge-primary')).getText()

    let bindisplayed = await element(by.css('.badge-info')).getText()

    let expectedDescription = locationDisplayed + " "+bindisplayed;

    console.log(text);
```

Here, the await ensures that the promise is resolved before it goes to the next line else each line will act asynchronously.

**Second: Chaining promise**

```
element(by.css('.badge-primary')).getText().then(function (locationDisplayed ) {

    element(by.css('.badge-info')).getText().then(function (bindisplayed ) {
    console.log(locationDisplayed+bindisplayed);
   });      

  });
```

The second option works only if the script has enough time for the call back to resolve. Try using `await browser.sleep(3000)` at the end